# Building a table using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

How can I transform a table from:

```
 drop table if exists simon;
 Create table simon (userId int, passageId int, score int);
 INSERT INTO simon (userId, passageId, score )
 VALUES
 (10, 1, 2),
 (10, 1, 3),
 (10, 2, 1),
 (10, 2, 3),
 (10, 2, 5),
 (11, 1, 1),
 (11, 2, 2),
 (11, 2, 3),
 (11, 3, 4);
```

To:

```
 userId passageId   score1 score2
 10    1            2      3
 10    2            1      3
 11    1            1      null
 11    2            2      3
 11    3            4      null
```

Note that only the first two scores are retained, so (10, 2, 5) is ignored.
I'm using sql to work in a mySQL database.

http://rextester.com/UYDRBF97169

Comment: Are scores always increasing? In other words, is it impossible for the second score to be less than the first score? Because there is no such thing as implicit order of rows in an SQL database. Unless we can infer the order by the data values, you can't do what you are asking.

Comment: No, scores can be any value

Comment: Define 'first'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should **define an order** to fetch values. For i.e. 2 most smallest scores or 2 most biggest score for each `userId` and `passageId`.

Following query will fetch 2 most **smallest** scores for each pair of `(userId,passageId)` and store it in table `simon2` as `score1` and `score2` respectively.

```
Create table simon2 (
    userId int, passageId int,
    score1 int,score2 int);    

insert into simon2(userId,passageId,score1,score2)
select
t1.userId,t1.passageId,t1.s1,
(select min(distinct score) 
 from simon s 
 where s.userId = t1.userId
 and   s.passageId = t1.passageId
 and   s.score > t1.s1
) as s2
 from 
(select userId,passageId,min(score) as S1
 from simon 
 group by userId,passageId) t1;
```

[Click for the Demo](http://rextester.com/SCEVZ23652)

**EDIT:**

Here is my another approach for the same task in order to give an efficient solution that can be used for larger data set.

To be honest, I don't know whether the following approach is better than previous one as it contains functions like `Group_concat()` and `Substring_Index()` which are not know as performance friendly.

But the positive point for my following solution as It doesn't require to sort the data (or scan the whole column within a group by) which was happening twice in my previous solution.

Nevertheless, here is my solution:

```
insert into simon2(userId,passageId,score1,score2)
select t.userId, t.passageId,
substring_index(t.scores,',',1) as score1,
(case when length(t.scores) > 1 then substring_index(t.scores,',',-1)
      else null
 end
) as score2
from 
(select userId,passageId,
substring_index (group_concat(score separator ','),',',2) as scores
from simon
group by userId,passageId) t;
```

[Click here for Demo 2](http://rextester.com/KYI58129)

**Note:** Solution 2 is not based on any increment or decrement order of `score`. It'll follow the same sequence as the sequence you get in result set of following query:

`select *from simon;`

And I think this is what you actually asked for in your question

Hope it helps!

Comment: The OP doesn't want the two lowest scores. They want the first two scores; it's just an unfortunate coincidence that the third score is always higher than the first two.

Comment: I know that and that's why I asked him to define an order.

Comment: But the order isn't based on largest (or smallest) values. This answer is misleading.

Comment: I already written the order I am using in my answer. If Op doesn't want to follow that, he/she won't. So, it's not misleading.

Comment: If OP wants to keep track of 2 scores of a user for a particular passage, there is nothing wrong in suggesting to keep track of 2 largest or smallest scores. Else, he can change schema(if he has privilege) by putting another id that keep track of insertion sequence of scores as you suggested.

Comment: I have your code working, it works well for up to about 3000 records, but then it slows dramatically. I am processing about 65K records. Should I ask you about this or do you think I should post another question?

Answer (score 0):

i have created this query in postgresql(split_part)
tomorrow  on i ll convert in mysql.. hope it will help you

```
select userid,passageid,
split_part(score,',',1)as first,
split_part(score,',',2)as second
from 
(
select userid,passageid,
string_agg(score,',')as score
from simon t2
group by userid,passageid
order by userid
)t
```